VS2022 crashes when setting specific color on a label in debug mode
When setting Label7.ForeColor = ColorDialog1.Color
or setting anything to colordialog1.color, vs2022 will become frozen.
Stepping into that line from a breakpoint, it is like it suspends itself, even though it is running in run mode, there is no yellow break line, that vanishes, no interaction in the code window.
the color structure exists inside colordialog1.color. All I can do is hot the stop button in the IDE.
If I set a breakpoint at If ColorDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then is fine, halted with yellow highlight. Step in, press F11, and nothing, still running, yellow line vanishes, no continuation, like weird suspend takes place.
The third line here is the line in question:
ColorDialog1.ShowDialog()
If ColorDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
   Label7.ForeColor = ColorDialog1.Color
End If

?ColorDialog1.Color 
"{Name=ffa47bc8, ARGB=(255, 164, 123, 200)}"
    A: 255
    B: 200
    G: 123
    IsEmpty: False
    IsKnownColor: False
    IsNamedColor: False
    IsSystemColor: False

?Label7.foreColor
"{Name=ffc0ffff, ARGB=(255, 192, 255, 255)}"
    A: 255
    B: 255
    G: 255
    IsEmpty: False
    IsKnownColor: False
    IsNamedColor: False
    IsSystemColor: False
    Name: "ffc0ffff"
    [R]: 192

Any advice on how to stop this behavior?

The R value seems to be missing from ColorDialog1.color details.  Was that a copy+paste error or is it actually missing?

Just a copy paste error on my part. It is there.


'ColorDialog1.ShowDialog()
If ColorDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
Label7.ForeColor = ColorDialog1.Color End If

I discovered cannot do colordialog1.showdialog twice as that code line actually loads the dialog box. Comment out the first, as to allow the second to run works.
